# Browsersync not reloading browser or injecting css

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, .net-core, gulp, browser-sync

I've been trying to get this straight for a few days now but haven't been able to get it working the way I need to. I'm unable to find any examples of other people using Browsersync with .net core, that may even be the reason I'm experiencing all of these issues. But I can't find any evidence that proves that and wouldn't understand why exactly that would be the case.

Anyway... I've got everything working in my gulp file exactly how I want it to for sass/js for handling errors, etc. I'm not new to gulp otherwise I'd blame my lack of experience for my inability to get this working.

Here's my gulp file followed by what the output is when running gulp.

Default Task:

```
const   gulp = require("gulp"),
        uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
        sass = require("gulp-sass"),
        rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        sassGlob = require('gulp-sass-glob'),
        postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
        cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
        concat = require('gulp-concat'),
        msbuild = require('gulp-msbuild'),
        through = require('through2'),
        notifier = require('node-notifier'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'compileJS'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy : {
            target: "https://localhost:3000",
        },
        files: ['./wwwroot/css/*'],

        rewriteRules: [
            {
                match: new RegExp('/css/main.min.css'),
                fn: function() {
                    return './wwwroot/css/main.min.css'
                }
            }
        ]
    });


    //Watch for any changes to the scss files.
    gulp.watch('./wwwroot/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

    //Watch for any changes to the js files, reload after those changes are made.
    gulp.watch('./wwwroot/js/source/*.js', ['compileJS']).on('change', browserSync.reload);

    //Watch for any changes to a .cshtml file and reload the browser if/when that change happens.
    gulp.watch("./**/*.cshtml").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);


/**
 * Compiles SASS files and stores the result into the public folder
 */
gulp.task('sass', function () {

    return gulp.src('./wwwroot/sass/main.scss')
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Sass Error:', err.toString());

            notifier.notify({
                'title': 'Gettin\' Sassy ‍♀️',
                'message': 'You goofed. Check your terminal window for more information.'
            });

            this.emit("end");
        }))
        .pipe(postcss([require('autoprefixer')]))
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
                cascade: false
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            through.obj(function(chunk, enc, cb) {
                cb(null, chunk)
            })
        )
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie8',
            level: 2}))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

/**
 * Compiles the Javascript files and stores the result in the public folder
 */
gulp.task('compileJS', function (done) {

    return gulp.src('./wwwroot/js/source/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('JS Uglify Error:', err.toString());

            notifier.notify({
                'title': 'JS Compile Error',
                'message': 'Something about your JS is a little off. Check yourself before you wreck yourself.'
            });

            this.emit("end");
        }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('../maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/js/dist'));
});
```

Output:

```
$ gulp
[21:34:15] Using gulpfile 
~/Repos/PROJECT_DIRECTORY/PROJECT_NAME/gulpfile.js
[21:34:15] Starting 'sass'...
[21:34:15] Starting 'compileJS'...
[21:34:15] Finished 'sass' after 437 ms
[21:34:15] Finished 'compileJS' after 426 ms
[21:34:15] Starting 'serve'...
[21:34:16] Finished 'serve' after 1 s
[21:34:16] Starting 'default'...
[21:34:16] Finished 'default' after 68 μs
[Browsersync] Proxying: https://localhost:3000
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
        Local: https://localhost:3000
     External: https://10.0.0.137:3000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 ------------------------------------
[21:34:35] Starting 'sass'...
[Browsersync] 1 file changed (main.min.css)
[21:34:35] Finished 'sass' after 207 ms
[21:34:58] Starting 'compileJS'...
[21:34:58] Finished 'compileJS' after 154 ms
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

So, looking at that output you would probably think to yourself, "This dude is an idiot... Browsersync states that it's reloading browsers..." Right, it does state that, but it is not reloading the browser. Browsersync also fails to inject my css into the browser as well.

As I mentioned, I've used gulp before, and this setup closely represents the gulp files that I use when doing Wordpress development as well. However, it won't work for this project (which has led me to my .net core / Visual Studio suspicions).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this

Create a env variable thats global to your application then above the closing  tag in your view you can add the following code.

This code is how I do it in Laravel with my Blade templates but it should be exactly the same you just need to replace it with the way .NET does it, I think they use Razor templating engine :)

```
  {{-- Live reload with browser sync --}}

  @if (!empty(env('APP_ENV')) && env('APP_ENV') === 'local') 
    <script 
      async 
      defer 
      src="{{ URL::to('/') . ':3000/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.7'}}">
    </script>
  @endif
```

Hope this helps you.

Just for interest sake below is my gulp pipeline:

```
const browserSync = require("browser-sync");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const reviser = require("gulp-rev");
const runSequence = require("run-sequence");

gulp.task("browserSync", function() {
  return browserSync.init({
    open: false,
    https: false,
    notify: false,
    injectChanges: true,
    proxy: "http://{site-name-here}.local/",
  });
});

gulp.task("compile:scss", function() {
  return (
    gulp
      // Gets the main.scss file
      .src("resources/assets/scss/main.scss")
      // Passes it through a gulp-sass, log errors to console
      .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
      // Adds versioning
      .pipe(reviser())
      // Add vendor prefixes
      .pipe(
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: ["last 2 versions"],
          cascade: false
        })
      )
      // Rename the file
      .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
      // Outputs it in the css folder
      .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css"))
      // Add sourcemaps
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      // Adds versioned file to manifest so we can access with the same name
      .pipe(reviser.manifest("manifest/rev-manifest.json"), { merge: true })
      // Outputs it in the css folder
      .pipe(gulp.dest("public/css")) 
      .pipe(
        browserSync.reload({
          // Reloading with Browser Sync
          stream: true
        })
      )
  );
});

// Watchers
gulp.task("watch", function() {
  gulp.watch(["./resources/assets/scss/**/*"], "compile:scss", browserSync.reload);
});

// Default task
gulp.task("start", function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    "browserSync",
    "compile:scss",
    "watch",
    callback
  );
});
```

to use it I just run `gulp start`

Keep in mind that running gulp like this you will need to have gulp installed globally. to do this run `npm install --global gulp-cli`